# What does the order of an element in a group really mean?

Tags: group-theory

Basically the idea is the order of a group is the number of elements in the group set. The order of an element is the number $k$ such that $a^k = e$. I can compute it, but what I dont really understand what this is suppose to represent?

Comment: Exactly that, the least number $k$ such that $a^k=e$. What else do you want to know?

Comment: So it does not tell me anything about $a$ specifically, it gives me a number I can multiply (or add) $a$ by itself until I get an identity. Can we say anything about that number in relationship to $a$ itself as an element? or all the elements of the group ?

Comment: ... the least *positive integer* $k$ such that $a^k = e$, assuming the group operation is written multiplicatively.

Comment: I tend to think about it as a "smaller" element.  Note that the order of a group and the order of an element are connected in that $\langle a\rangle$ has the same order (as a sub group) as the element $a$ has (as an element).  So $|\langle a\rangle| = |a|$, where $|\cdot |$ means a different (but related) thing on each side.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't tell you anything about $a$? It tells you the least number of times you multiply/add $a$ to itself to get the identity. That is definitely telling you something about $a$.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Thanks man I was expecting like some properties that the order has. I am unsure what I could do with that piece of information. I am still studying group and ring theory.  I thnk as what mark said, the generator of a group has the same order as the element itself, so if I want to find a generator for a group, I would check every order of every element and determine which one has the same as the group, then check if its the generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of $a$ is the order of the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$, i.e. the order of the group $<a>=\left\{a^k\mid|k\in\mathbb Z\right\}$.

So it has everything to do with the order of a group :-)